# Radio Buttons not showing up as checked

Tags: php, html, wordpress, radio-button, wordpress-theming

I'm currently trying to write a theme options page for Wordpress. In it, the user could select the alignment of the DIV through radio buttons.

Currently it looks like this when an option is selected: https://gyazo.com/e27c2fc2c2e1f751ab27d98453581c52

I was wondering how I'd fix that (for the radio buttons to actually show up as checked and not as checked='checked'Center). It works and it correctly outputs to front-end but it just doesn't show up as checked without the checked='checked'. If I use jquery to remove *checked='checked'* it removes the radio buttons all together.

```
register_setting('slider_setting','slider_section1_direction');
add_settings_section( 'slider_section', '', 'slider_settings_callback', 'register_slider_settings' );
add_settings_field( 'slider_section1_direction', '', 'slider_section1_direction_callback', 'register_slider_settings', 'slider_section' );


function slider_section1_radio_buttons_callback() {
    $s1_radio_buttons_settings = array(
      'left' => array(
          'value' => 'left',
          'label' => 'Left'
        ),
      'center' => array(
          'value' => 'center',
          'label' => 'Center'
        ),
      'right' => array(
          'value' => 'right',
          'label' => 'Right'
        ),
    );

  return apply_filters( 'slider_section1_radio_buttons_callback', $s1_radio_buttons_settings );
  }

  function slider_section1_direction_callback() {
    $settings = get_option('slider_section1_direction');
    echo '<div class="setting">';
    echo '<div class="setting-header half-width-header">';
    esc_attr_e('Slider Text Alignment');
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="setting-body" style="margin-top: 5px">';

    // RADIO BUTTONS
    foreach ( slider_section1_radio_buttons_callback() as $s1_button ) {
      echo '<label class="description" style="margin-right: 40px">';
        echo "<input type='radio'" . checked( $settings['s1_radio_buttons_settings'], $s1_button['value'] ) . " name='slider_section1_direction[s1_radio_buttons_settings]' value='" . esc_attr( $s1_button['value'] ) . "'/>";
        echo $s1_button['label'];
      echo '</label>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
    echo '</div>';
  }

 function slider_settings_callback() {
     }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your checked function you're using in your input please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) for the `checked` function, and it looks like it normally echos the `checked="checked"` attribute. However, because you want to concatenate it to a string, you want to return the attribute instead. Luckily the third parameter in that function can be set to `false` to cause the function to return the attribute instead. So just change your usage of the function to this:

```
checked( $settings['s1_radio_buttons_settings'], $s1_button['value'], false)
```

Notice the `false` at the end of the function.

Comment: Actually, when I set the third parameter to false it returns the attribute instead instead of echoing the attribute. According to the documentation, the default is true. I'll still mark your answer as correct though and thanks for helping!